# Querying nested properties in mongo with c# and linq

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I'm trying to use linq queries to filter results from Mongo, but none of my queries using complex objects work:

The following works just fine :

```
query.Where(o => (o.Name == "Joe"))
```

But this gives me errors:

```
query.Where(o => (o.Address.HouseNumber == "1234"))
```

With version 2.1.1 of the c# drivers if I use the legacy drivers I get:

> Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression:
>   p.Address.HouseNumber
>
> at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Utils.BsonSerializationInfoFinder.GetSerializationInfo(Expression
>   node, Dictionary`2 serializationInfoCache)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Utils.BsonSerializationInfoHelper.GetSerializationInfo(Expression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildComparisonQuery(Expression
>   variableExpression, ExpressionType operatorType, ConstantExpression
>   constantExpression)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildComparisonQuery(BinaryExpression
>   binaryExpression)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildQuery(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildAndAlsoQuery(BinaryExpression
>   binaryExpression)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildQuery(Expression
>   expression)    at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.SelectQuery.BuildQuery()    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.SelectQuery.Execute()    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) 
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Core.Persistence.LegacyMongoDb.LegacyMongoDbImp.<QueryAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Users...\src\Core.Persistence.LegacyMongoDb\LegacyMongoDb.Implementation.cs:line
>   84

If I use the current version of the drivers I get:

> [Address].HouseNumber is not supported.
>
> at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.GetFieldExpression(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(Expression
>   variableExpression, ExpressionType operatorType, ConstantExpression
>   constantExpression)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(BinaryExpression
>   binaryExpression)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression
>   node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateWhere(WhereExpression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateSkip(SkipExpression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateTake(TakeExpression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslatePipeline(PipelineExpression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression
>   node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Translate(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression
>   expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryableImpl`2.ToCursorAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__4`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at Core.Persistence.MongoDb.MongoDbImp.<QueryAsync>d__12`1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Users...\libs\mojio.core\src\Core.Persistence.MongoDb\MongoDb.Implementation.cs:line
>   68

I'm super stuck any help in the right direction would be appreciated

EDIT:

```
public class User : Base<User>, IUser
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public IAddress Address { get; set; }
}


public class Address : IAddress
{
     public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
     public string Country { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing it using complex objects and it seems to be working for me. What version of Mongo C# driver are you using? Can you give more details about your complex objects? Maybe listing the properties of both the objects would help.

Comment: It wasn't working with version 1.1.1.5 so I updated to 2.2.3 and I've updated the question to include details about the object

Comment: In this case, what is `query`?

Comment: {aggregate([]).Where(p => p.Deleted.Equals(False)).Where(m => m.Index.Any(guid => value(Base`1+<>c__DisplayClass7_0[User]).index.Contains(guid))).Where(o => (o.Address.HouseNumber== "1234"))}

Comment: And this is for the one that works at the same point in the code: aggregate([{ "$match" : { "Deleted" : false } }, { "$match" : { "_" : { "$in" : [CSUUID("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"), CSUUID("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"), CSUUID("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)] } } }, { "$match" : { "Name" : "Jerry" } }])}